# Intuition for iterated function for log log log n.

Tags: functions, logarithms, intuition

Intuitively, $\log n$ (base 2) is the number of times you have to divide $n$ by 2 before reaching a number around 2. (Waving our hands a little to gloss over floor vs ceiling and $\pm$ 1 errors.) Similarly, $\log \log n$ is the number of times we have to iterate the square root function to get from $n$ down to a number around $2$ (waving our hands again).

What is the intuition for $\log \log \log n$? What is the function that you would iterate $\log \log \log n$ times to get from $n$ down to a small constant?

Comment: Please explain *iterate the square root function*...and please wave your hands, only if really needed.

Comment: @draks: Consider the sequence $n, \sqrt n, \sqrt{\sqrt n}, \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt n}} \ldots$

Comment: A deleted comment read: "According to a joke in analytic number theory, $\log\log\log x<4$ for all $x$."

Comment: @anon, glad you caught it ;)

Comment: For one logarithm, you are halving $n$ at each step.  For two logarithms, you are halving $n$'s logarithm at each step, or taking the square root of $n$.  For three logarithms, you are taking the square root of $n$'s logarithm at each step.

Comment: @anon: What I've heard is that it goes to infinity "with great dignity" (attr. Dan Shanks).

Comment: @Charles yes, see my answer.

Comment: This is not directly relevant to the question, but Joe will probably be interested to learn about [the iterated logarithm function](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Log-star), which counts the number of times one must take the logarithm of its argument before the result is less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\log$, you have $n \mapsto n/2$, which is really $n\mapsto\exp(\log n - 1)$, where $\exp$ is exponentiation with base $2$, i.e. $n\mapsto 2^n$ :-)

For $\log\circ\log$, you have $n\mapsto\sqrt n=\exp\big(\!\frac{\log n}2\!\big)=\exp\exp(\log\log n - 1)$.

So for $\log\circ\log\circ\log$, you'll have $n\mapsto\exp\exp\exp(\log\log\log n - 1)$, which simplifies to... $$n\mapsto2^\sqrt{\log_2 n}.$$
Not very pretty, I'm afraid.

*Edit:* In retrospect, it's kind of obvious that if you want an iteration that takes about $f(n)$ steps to reach some value, then all you need to do is decrease $f(n)$ by a fixed amount per iteration. So if the iterated function is $n \mapsto m$, you can choose $f(m) = f(n)-1$, so $m = f^{-1}(f(n)-1)$. For example, it should take about $\sqrt n$ iterations of $n\mapsto(\sqrt n-1)^2=n-2\sqrt n+1$ to map $n$ to something less than $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from [Daniel Shanks](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1959-13-068/S0025-5718-1959-0108470-8/):

> Since $ \;  \log \log \log n \rightarrow \infty \;$ (with great dignity)
>   these inequalities imply...